# How can I use Xcode's `Find and Replace` on Multiline blocks of text

Tags: regex, xcode, multiline, nsregularexpression

I have a large file with hundreds of blocks of text (parts of C++ method calls) that resemble the `Current` block below and I wish to use **Xcode’s Regular Expression replacement** to change each one to resemble the `Desired` block below, capturing values 0.89f, A name, 0.1, 0.5 and 2.

[image: Current Block]

[image: Desired Block]

Note that both blocks start and end with `new Zapp` and `//d.p.’s to show` respectively so to save myself loads of manual editing I wish to use regex search and replace.

The main problem I face is the `multi-line` nature of the blocks.  If we ignore that for a moment, I have ALMOST performed a search and replace on the following `single-line` blocks:

Current:

[image: Current Single-Line]

`new Zapp (0.89f  // defaultParameterValue , "A name" // name , 0.1     // min , 0.5 // max , 2    // d.p.'s to show`

Desired:

[image: Desired Single-Line]

`new Zapp  (NormalisableRange<float> (0.1, 0.5) ,NormalisableRange<float> (0.1, 0.5).convertTo0to1(0.89f) , "A name"     // name  , 2        // d.p.'s to show`

**The Find and Replace:**

**Find**: `Zapp\s+\((.*)\s+// defaultParameterValue\s+,\s+"(.*)"\s+\/\/\s+name\s+,\s+(.*)\s+\/\/\s+min\s+,\s+(.*)\s+\/\/\s+max\s+,\s+(.*)\s+\/\/\s+d.p.'s`

**Replace**: `Zapp  (NormalisableRange<float> ($3, $4) ,NormalisableRange<float> ($3, $4).convertTo0to1($1) , "$2"     // name  , $5        // d.p.’s`

This **single-line** solution has the problem that additional white-space is seen after capture 1 (1 space), capture 3 (4 spaces) and capture 5 (3 spaces), otherwise it works well:

[image: Comparison of Search and Replace output and ideal output]

I tried to eliminate the whitespace from capture 1 (0.89f), capture 3 (0.1) and capture 5 (2) using `[^\s]+` but it didn't help so if anybody can point out the reason for that I'd be grateful.

[image]

I can, for what it's worth, search for `upper` and `lower` using `\s+` but I can't put it all together to achieve the desired result.

I've seen some old posts online that suggest this task might not be possible with Xcode.  If that is true, can anybody suggest an alternative approach that will get the job done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is the `.*` is too greedy and match the whitespace that could have been matched by  the `\s+` pattern but for this greedy subpattern.

Either use the lazy/reluctant `.*?`:

```
Zapp\s+\((.*?)\s+// defaultParameterValue\s+,\s+"(.*)"\s+\/\/\s+name\s+,\s+(.*?)\s+\/\/\s+min\s+,\s+(.*?)\s+\/\/\s+max\s+,\s+(.*?)\s+\/\/\s+d.p.'s
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wB6wR0/1)

Or define the class for matching floats/integers `[-+\w.]+` (a bit not precise, but will do since the expected value type is known) or double quoted literals (`"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"`):

```
Zapp\s+\(([-+\w.]+)\s+// defaultParameterValue\s+,\s+"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"\s+\/\/\s+name\s+,\s+([-+\w.]+)\s+\/\/\s+min\s+,\s+([-+\w.]+)\s+\/\/\s+max\s+,\s+([-+\d.]+)\s+\/\/\s+d.p.'s
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/wB6wR0/2)

Comment: Both your answers satisfy the question in general so I’ll mark this as the correct answer.  

Actually pasting your code into Xcode’s Find and Replace box fails to match the text but this seems to be a limitation with multi-line blocks in Xcode.  I have provided an answer myself using AppCode which does allow a multi-line search term, just to help others that might use AppCode.  Thanks for your answer, I learnt something.

Answer (score 0):

Please see Wiktor's answer.  He gives two solutions with demos that satisfy the problem in general.

However, thanks to Rich’s answer [Multi line search and replace tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268045/multi-line-search-and-replace-tool),  I discovered [AppCode by JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) will indeed do a multi-line search and replace:

SEARCH:

`new Zapp\s+\(([^\s]+)\s+// defaultParameterValue\n\s+"(.*)"\s+\/\/\s+name\s+, ([^\s]+)\s+// min\n,\s+([^\s]+)\s+// max\n,\s+([^\s]+)\s+// d.p.'s to show`

REPLACE:

`new Zapp     (NormalisableRange<float> ($3, $4)\n\t ,NormalisableRange<float> ($3, $4).convertTo0to1($1)\n\t\t\t , "$2"             // name\n\t\t\t , $5                                        // d.p.'s to show`